# How to fix LibreOffice after running `sudo libreoffice`?

Tags: sudo, libreoffice

Is my first question here because Ubuntu never gives me any problems but yesterday I did a very stupid thing.

Any time LibreOffice starts, it says that is impossible to recover a file on a mounted disk.  I thought that it must be because of a permissions issue and that the best solution was to give LibreOffice superuser permissions.

I tried from a terminal

```
sudo libreoffice
```

Since I did that it is impossible to open LibreOffice in the usual way.  I can only start the app as superuser from a terminal using `sudo`.

When using the usual ways (with my normal user) I get a Fatal Error:

> Can't start the application, can't complete user install.

(In Spanish)

[image: Libreoffice start after using "sudo libreoffice"]

How can I restore the application or reinstall the user configuration?

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 in Spanish language, but I suppose the same would apply to other distros when LibreOffice is started using `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

Close libreoffice, then run:

```
sudo chown -R $USER: ~/.config/libreoffice/
```

it should fix all necessary ownership problems.

If it didn't work, then try moving the broken configuration files:

```
sudo mv ~/.config/libreoffice{,-rm}
```

Comment: hmm, dont works...

Comment: Dont't worked, now even dont shown the error message :-s  Appear that libreoffice create more config files somewhere else, I have also installed and unistalled libreoffice wilthout success.

Comment: I'll let you know if I came up with an alternative ;)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help.

The problem was solved this way:

delete ~/.config/libreoffice and then:

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure libreoffice

I lost some personal config, libreoffice become as a new install but now works well.